# Attempting to access a class from a string

Tags: java

I did my best with the title, but its probably not a good way to word it, so instead I'll do my best to explain the problem. For those familiar with Windows BATCH, this code

```
set /p var =
goto %var%
```

will take you to the page whose name is the String stored in the variable `var`. I need to do the same thing in Java. Yes, I am fully aware that using `if` statements would be satisfactory for this idea, except that it requires many more lines of code. My approach was this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class blarg {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NullPointerException{

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String spell = scan.nextLine();

        ClassLoader cl = null;

        Class cls = (cl.loadClass(spell)).class;
        String name = cls.getName();

        cl.loadClass(name);


    }

}
```

My goal here (in case it isn't clear, because I don't know if its possible or if I'm using the proper code) is to take the user's input to a variable `spell`. Then, I used `Class cls = (cl.loadClass(spell)).class` to get the class associated with `spell`, and then take that class, get the fully qualified name with `String name = cls.getName();`, and finally to load that class.

I get the following error in Eclipse:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: Syntax error on token "class", Identifier expected

So, is there some way that I can work around that syntax error (by adding an identifier), or else does anyone else know of a way to do what I am trying to do? If not, I am in no way opposed to the use of `if` statements, I just figured I could make my life easier if I could make this work. If you need any more information, I'll give you what I can.

Comment: `loadClass` already loads the class and returns a `Class` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rules for using `.class` are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class,
>   interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed
>   by a '.' and the token class.

So you can't use it like so

```
Class cls = (cl.loadClass(spell)).class;
```

The `loadClass()` method already loads your class, just use

```
Class cls = cl.loadClass(spell);
```

assuming `spell` contains the fully qualified class name.

You wouldn't be able to find a class with `forName()` unless it was the fully qualified name anyway.

---

**Don't forget to get a `ClassLoader` reference.**

Comment: Okay, I get that, and removing .class changes the error. spell IS NOT a fully qualified class name, it is just a string, containing a class name. How do I arrange the code so that i get the fully qualified name from spell.class? (Remember, spell is a string variable, not the actual class name.)

Comment: @JDtheDueler Read the [javadoc for `forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)). The argument you pass it must be `the fully qualified name of the desired class`. If you are looking to iterate through all the classes in your classpath to match those whose simple name matches your input, that's a different question altogether.

Comment: I understand that the fully qualified name is required. I think that I am not being clear. Lets say I want to load the class tuna. I type tuna into the string `spell`. I then need to convert the value of `spell` to a fully qualified class name. That is what is stopping me and why I can't seem to follow your answer. Spell DOES NOT contain the fully qualified name, just the name. How do I make it have the fuly qualified name?

Comment: @JDtheDueler That's not how it works. How can the application know that you mean `com.mycompany.tuna` instead of `com.someother.company.tuna`? You can use `loadClass()` and `forName` only with fully qualified class names.

Comment: So then the answer here is that the idea is not feasible? That is fine. I wanted to make sure, because I understand that Java is an OOP language and the place that I got the idea from is a POP language. Thank you for the help. I guess that I have to use if statements after all.

Comment: @JDtheDueler You can't directly do it like so, no. A possibility is to iterate through all the classes on the classpath, and choose X given the name you want. There are a few examples of this on SO if you search.

Comment: You could use a look-up table, like a HashMap. The keys would be the spell name, the values would be the fully qualified classname. So `Class cls = cl.loadClass(spell);` becomes `Class cls = cl.loadClass(lookUp.get(spell));`

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
Class<?> myclass = Class.forName(spell);
```

Comment: Okay, now can you please explain to me what exactly that is doing? Most importantly, how is that actually accessing a class? I am having difficulty with the syntax. And thank you for the quick answer.

Comment: IMO, it is completely pointless to use `forName` to then immediately call `loadClass()`.

Answer (score 0):

you code have serious problems.

first you need to instantiate ClassLoader:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
```

Secondly, Any class name provided as a String parameter to methods in `ClassLoader` must be a binary name as defined by The Java™ Language Specification.

Examples of valid class names include:

```
   "java.lang.String"
   "javax.swing.JSpinner$DefaultEditor"
   "java.security.KeyStore$Builder$FileBuilder$1"
   "java.net.URLClassLoader$3$1"
```

Third, you should call `loadClass` method as follows:

```
Class clazz = cl.loadClass(name);
```